# How to add adMob Banner into getView using the latest SDK - com.google.android.gms.ads

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm trying to add adMob Banner ads into the getView method used for my ListView in one of my fragments. I'm using the latest adMob SDK (com.google.android.gms.ads.).

I'm only finding examples which use the older versions of the Google SDK. If anyone has a link to example of a current version of Google admob  please let me know.

FYI - I took Tim's suggestion. I found a complete sample of code from http://jmsliu.com/1482/adding-admob-banner-in-android-listview-header.html.

Its a different one that I first showed you but is set up with 3 Activities. After several hours of testing I thought I  would show you my code and the error I'm currently getting, and the original code. I added "Log.i" throughout the program to determine which line causes the abend. It appears that the ads is returning null. Also, note that the original version of code (after the error section) has special "keytwordSet" logic. I was unable to get rid of the syntax errors so I removed it from my version.

> `AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
>     Set keywordsSet = new HashSet();
>     keywordsSet.add("game");
>     keywordsSet.add("dating");
>     keywordsSet.add("money");
>     keywordsSet.add("girl");
>     adRequest.addKeywords(keywordsSet);
>     adView.loadAd(adRequest);`

## New Code:

> - PostItemAdapter.java
> - - Adapter Class which configs and returns the View for ListView
> - */
>     package com.jms.admobinlistview;
>
>   import java.util.HashSet;
>     import java.util.Set; 
>     import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
>     import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
>     import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
>     import com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobExtras;
>     import android.app.Activity;
>     import android.content.Context;
>     import android.os.Bundle;
>     import android.util.Log;
>     import android.view.LayoutInflater;
>     import android.view.View;
>     import android.view.ViewGroup;
>     import android.widget.AbsListView;
>     import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
>     import android.widget.ImageView;
>     import android.widget.LinearLayout;
>     import android.widget.TextView;
>
>   public class PostItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
>       private LayoutInflater inflater;
>       private PostData[] datas;
>       private Activity mainActivity;
>       private AdView adView;
>
>   public PostItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
>               PostData[] objects) {
>           super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
>           // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
>           mainActivity = (Activity) context;
>           inflater = mainActivity.getLayoutInflater();
>           datas = objects;
>       }
>
>   static class ViewHolder {
>           TextView postTitleView;
>           TextView postDateView;
>           ImageView postThumbView;
>       }
>
>   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>           ViewHolder viewHolder;
>
>   ```
>     if (position == 0) {
>         if (convertView == null || !(convertView instanceof AdView)) {
>             if (adView == null) {
>                 Log.i("1", "msg1");
>                 AdView adView = new AdView(mainActivity);
>               Log.i("2", "msg2");
>
>                 adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4409647944042499/8301167762");
>                 Log.i("3", "msg3");
>
>                 adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);                    
>                 Log.i("4", "msg4");
>
>                    // Convert the default layout parameters so that they play >                                          nice with
>                 // ListView.
>
>                 float density = mainActivity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics>  
>                         ().density;
>             int height = Math.round(AdSize.BANNER.getHeight() * density);
>             AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
>                 AbsListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
>                 height);
>             adView.setLayoutParams(params);
>
>             AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
>                 .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
>                 .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
>                 .build();
>             Log.i("5", "msg5");
>
>                 adView.loadAd(adRequest);
>                 Log.i("6", "msg6");
>
>             }
>             Log.i("7", "msg7");
>
>             convertView = adView;
>             Log.i("8", "msg8");
>
>         }
>     } else {
>         Log.i("8", "msg8");
>
>         if (convertView == null || convertView instanceof AdView) {
>             Log.i("9", "msg9");
>
>             convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.postitem, null);
>             Log.i("10", "msg10");
>
>             viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
>             Log.i("11", "msg11");
>
>             viewHolder.postThumbView = (ImageView) convertView
>                     .findViewById(R.id.postThumb);
>             Log.i("12", "msg12");
>
>             viewHolder.postTitleView = (TextView) convertView
>                     .findViewById(R.id.postTitleLabel);
>             Log.i("13", "msg13");
>
>             viewHolder.postDateView = (TextView) convertView
>                     .findViewById(R.id.postDateLabel);
>             Log.i("14", "msg14");
>
>             convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
>             Log.i("15", "msg15");
>
>         } else {
>             Log.i("16", "msg16");
>
>             viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
>             Log.i("17", "msg17");
>
>         }
>         Log.i("18", "msg18");
>
>         if (datas[position].postThumbUrl == null) {
>             Log.i("19", "msg19");
>
>             viewHolder.postThumbView
>                     .setImageResource(R.drawable.postthumb_loading);
>         }
>         Log.i("20", "msg20");
>
>         viewHolder.postTitleView.setText(datas[position].postTitle);
>         viewHolder.postDateView.setText(datas[position].postDate);
>     }
>     Log.i("21", "msg21");
>
>     return convertView;
>   ```
>
>   }
>     }
>
>   ## Error:
>
>   `03-16 21:34:10.509: I/1(415): msg1
>     03-16 21:34:10.530: I/2(415): msg2
>     03-16 21:34:10.530: I/3(415): msg3
>     03-16 21:34:10.530: I/4(415): msg4
>     03-16 21:34:10.582: I/5(415): msg5
>     03-16 21:34:10.609: D/dalvikvm(415): DexOpt: couldn't find field
>     Landroid/content/res/Configuration;.smallestScreenWidthDp
>     03-16 21:34:10.609: W/dalvikvm(415): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 36
>     03-16 21:34:10.609: D/dalvikvm(415): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0012
>     03-16 21:34:10.623: D/dalvikvm(415): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0018 in
>
>     Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b (Landroid/content/res/Resources;)Z
>     03-16 21:34:10.649: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(415): Google Play Store is missing.
>     03-16 21:34:10.730: D/dalvikvm(415): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads256706667.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
>     03-16 21:34:10.919: D/dalvikvm(415): DexOpt: --- END 'ads256706667.jar' (success) ---
>     03-16 21:34:10.919: D/dalvikvm(415): DEX
>
>     prep '/data/data/com.jms.admobinlistview/cache/ads256706667.jar': unzip in 2ms, rewrite 193ms
>     03-16 21:34:11.019: I/Ads(415): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice
>
>     ("B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB") to get test ads on this device.
>     03-16 21:34:11.059: I/Ads(415): Starting ad request.
>     03-16 21:34:11.179: D/dalvikvm(415): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 269K, 52% free 2677K/5575K,
>
>     external 2032K/2137K, paused 74ms
>     03-16 21:34:11.499: I/6(415): msg6
>     03-16 21:34:11.499: I/7(415): msg7
>     03-16 21:34:11.499: I/8(415): msg8
>     03-16 21:34:11.509: I/21(415): msg21
>     03-16 21:34:11.509: D/AndroidRuntime(415): Shutting down VM
>     03-16 21:34:11.509: W/dalvikvm(415): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>
>     (group=0x40015560)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415): java.lang.NullPointerException
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView
>
>     (AbsListView.java:1432)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView
>
>     (ListView.java:1745)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown
>
>     (ListView.java:670)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop
>
>     (ListView.java:727)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren
>
>     (ListView.java:1598)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout
>
>     (AbsListView.java:1260)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame
>
>     (LinearLayout.java:1254)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical
>
>     (LinearLayout.java:1130)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout
>     (LinearLayout.java:1047)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout
>     (FrameLayout.java:338)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame
>
>     (LinearLayout.java:1254)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical
>     (LinearLayout.java:1130)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout
>
>     (LinearLayout.java:1047)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout
>     (FrameLayout.java:338)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals
>
>     (ViewRoot.java:1140)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage
>     (ViewRoot.java:1859)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
>     (Handler.java:99)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main
>
>     (ActivityThread.java:3683)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native 
>     Method)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at 
>     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>     (ZygoteInit.java:597)
>     03-16 21:34:11.589: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>     03-16 21:34:17.879: I/Process(415): Sending signal. PID: 415 SIG: 9`

## Original Code with previous version of adMob:

> /**
>      * PostItemAdapter.java
>      * 
>      * Adapter Class which configs and returns the View for ListView
>      * 
>      */
>      package com.jms.admobinlistview;
>
> import java.util.HashSet;
>      import java.util.Set;
>
> import android.app.Activity;
>      import android.content.Context;
>      import android.view.LayoutInflater;
>      import android.view.View;
>      import android.view.ViewGroup;
>      import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
>      import android.widget.ImageView;
>      import android.widget.TextView;
>
> import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
>      import com.google.ads.AdSize;
>      import com.google.ads.AdView;
>
> public class PostItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
>         private LayoutInflater inflater;
>         private PostData[] datas;
>         private Activity mainActivity;
>         private AdView adView;
>
> ```
>   public PostItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
>           PostData[] objects) {
>       super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
>       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
>       mainActivity = (Activity) context;
>       inflater = mainActivity.getLayoutInflater();
>       datas = objects;
>   }
>
>   static class ViewHolder {
>       TextView postTitleView;
>       TextView postDateView;
>       ImageView postThumbView;
>   }
>
>   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>       ViewHolder viewHolder;
>
>       if (position == 0) {
>           if (convertView == null || !(convertView instanceof AdView)) {
>               if (adView == null) {
>                   adView = new AdView(mainActivity, AdSize.SMART_BANNER,
>                           "a151bd35eeb068d");
>                   AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
>                   Set<String> keywordsSet = new HashSet<String>();
>                   keywordsSet.add("game");
>                   keywordsSet.add("dating");
>                   keywordsSet.add("money");
>                   keywordsSet.add("girl");
>                   adRequest.addKeywords(keywordsSet);
>                   adView.loadAd(adRequest);
>               }
>
>               convertView = adView;
>           }
>       } else {
>           if (convertView == null || convertView instanceof AdView) {
>               convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.postitem, null);
>
>               viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
>               viewHolder.postThumbView = (ImageView) convertView
>                       .findViewById(R.id.postThumb);
>               viewHolder.postTitleView = (TextView) convertView
>                       .findViewById(R.id.postTitleLabel);
>               viewHolder.postDateView = (TextView) convertView
>                       .findViewById(R.id.postDateLabel);
>               convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
>           } else {
>               viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
>           }
>
>           if (datas[position].postThumbUrl == null) {
>               viewHolder.postThumbView
>                       .setImageResource(R.drawable.postthumb_loading);
>           }
>
>           viewHolder.postTitleView.setText(datas[position].postTitle);
>           viewHolder.postDateView.setText(datas[position].postDate);
>       }
>
>       return convertView;
>   }
> ```
>
> }

*===============================================================================*

Tim, thanks for getting back to me. The following is my code and error message that I'm getting. I tried several things and I keep getting the same type of errors. Can you please clarify your explanation you gave? Is purview really preview?

> `package com.robertrichardson.bxxxyxxxxzxxxxLite;`
>
> import java.util.ArrayList;
>     import java.util.HashSet;
>     import java.util.Set;
>
> import android.annotation.TargetApi;
>     import android.content.Context;
>     import android.content.Intent;
>     import android.database.DataSetObserver;
>     import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
>     import android.os.Build;
>     import android.os.Bundle;
>     import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
>     import android.text.format.DateFormat;
>     import android.util.Log;
>     import android.view.ContextMenu;
>     import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
>     import android.view.LayoutInflater;
>     import android.view.View;
>     import android.view.ViewGroup;
>     import android.widget.AbsListView;
>     import android.widget.AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener;
>     import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
>     import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
>     import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
>     import android.widget.Button;
>     import android.widget.CheckBox;
>     import android.widget.ImageButton;
>     import android.widget.LinearLayout;
>     import android.widget.ListView;
>     import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
>     import android.widget.TextView;
>
> import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;
>     import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
>     import android.app.Activity;
>
> import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
>     import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
>     import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder;
>     import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
>     import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
>     import com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdRequest;
>     import com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView;
>     import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.internal.InFilter;
>     import com.robertrichardson.bxxxyxxxxzxxxxLite.R.string;
>
> /*
>      * BxxxxListFragment Class: Sets up and displays all Bxxxx Activity on the list.
>      */
>
> public class BxxxxListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
>
> ```
>   private ArrayList<Bxxxx> mBxxxx;
>   private boolean mSubtitleVisible;
>   private LayoutInflater inflater;
>   private Activity mainActivity;
>
>   private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-4409647944042499/8301167762";
>
>   public static final String TAG = "BxxxxListFragment";
> ```
>
> //   private AdView adView;
>         private AdView adView;
>
> ```
>   @Override
>   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       /*
>        * New ads Logic    
>        */
>
>       setHasOptionsMenu(true);
>       getSherlockActivity().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
>       mBxxxx = BxxxxLab.get(getSherlockActivity()).getBxxxx();
>       BxxxxAdapter adapter = new BxxxxAdapter(mBxxxx);
>       setListAdapter(adapter);
>       setRetainInstance(true);
>       mSubtitleVisible = false;
>       }
>
>   @Override
>   public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onViewCreated(view,  savedInstanceState);
>
>       setEmptyText(getResources().getString(string.new_bxxxx_attack_empty_desc));
>
>       registerForContextMenu(getListView());
>       setHasOptionsMenu(true);
>   } 
>
>   @TargetApi(11)
>   @Override
>      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
>           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
>         View v = super.onCreateView(inflater,  parent,  savedInstanceState);
>
>       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
>           if (mSubtitleVisible) {
>               getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(R.string.subtitle);
>           }
>       }
>
>       ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
>
>       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
>
>           // Use floating point context menus on Froyer and Gingerbread
>           registerForContextMenu(listView);
>
>       } else {
>
>           // Use contextual action bar on Honeycomb and higher
>           listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
>           listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener()  {
>
>               public boolean onActionItemClicked(
>                       android.view.ActionMode arg0, android.view.MenuItem arg1) {
>                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>                   return false;
>               }
>
>
>               public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode,
>                       android.view.Menu menu) {
>                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>                   return false;
>               }
>
>               public void onDestroyActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode) {
>                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>               }
>               public boolean onPrepareActionMode(
>                       android.view.ActionMode mode, android.view.Menu menu) {
>                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>                   return false;
>               }
>
>               public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(
>                       android.view.ActionMode mode, int position, long id,
>                       boolean checked) {
>                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>               }
>
>           // ActionMode.Callback methods
>       }); 
>   }
>          return v;
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
>   @Override
>   public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
>       Bxxxx c = ((BxxxxAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
>       // Start Bxxxx Activity
>       Intent i = new Intent(getSherlockActivity(), BxxxxPagerActivity.class);
>       i.putExtra(BxxxxFragment.EXTRA_BULLIED_ID, c.getId());
>       startActivityForResult(i, 0);
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {>   
>       ((BxxxxAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public void onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
>       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
>       inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_bxxxx_list, menu);
>    }
>
>   @TargetApi(11)
>   @Override
>   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item)
>   {
>       switch (item.getItemId()) {
>       case R.id.settings:
>          Intent i=new Intent(getSherlockActivity(), Preferences.class); 
>          startActivity(i);
>          return(true);
>       case R.id.about:
>          i=new Intent(getSherlockActivity(),BxxxxContentActivity.class);
>          i.putExtra(BxxxxContentActivity.EXTRA_FILE,
>          "file:///android_asset/misc/about.html");
>          startActivity(i);
>          return(true);
>       case R.id.help:
>          i=new Intent(getSherlockActivity(),BxxxxContentActivity.class);
>          i.putExtra(BxxxxContentActivity.EXTRA_FILE,
>          "file:///android_asset/misc/help.html");
>          startActivity(i);
>          return(true);
>       case R.id.disclaimer:
>          i=new Intent(getSherlockActivity(),BxxxxContentActivity.class);
>          i.putExtra(BxxxxContentActivity.EXTRA_FILE,
>          "file:///android_asset/misc/disclaimer.html");
>          startActivity(i);
>           return(true);
>       case R.id.menu_item_new_bxxxx:
>           Bxxxx bxxxx = new Bxxxx();
>           BxxxxLab.get(getSherlockActivity()).addBxxxx(bxxxx);
>           i = new Intent(getSherlockActivity(), BxxxxPagerActivity.class);
>           i.putExtra(BxxxxFragment.EXTRA_BULLIED_ID,  bxxxx.getId());
>           startActivityForResult(i,0);
>           return true;
>       default:
>           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
>       }
>    }
>
>   @Override
>   public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu,View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
>       getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bxxxx_list_item_context, menu);
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
>       AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
>       int position = info.position;
>       BxxxxAdapter adapter = (BxxxxAdapter)getListAdapter();
>       Bxxxx bxxxx = adapter.getItem(position);
>
>       switch (item.getItemId()) {
>          case R.id.menu_item_delete_bxxxx:
>              BxxxxLab.get(getActivity()).deleteBxxxx(bxxxx);
>              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
>              return true;
>       }
>       return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
>   }
>
>   private class BxxxxAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Bxxxx> {
>       public BxxxxAdapter(ArrayList<Bxxxx> bxxxx) {
>           super(getSherlockActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bxxxx);
>       }    
>
>   @Override
>   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
> ```
>
> /*
>      * New ads Logic
>      */
>              Log.i("1", "msg1");
>
> ```
>       if (position == 0)
>       {
>           if (convertView == null || !(convertView instanceof AdView)) {
>               if (adView == null) {
>                   Log.i("2", "msg2");
>
>                   adView = new AdView(mainActivity); <=== Abends on this line
>
>                   Log.i("3", "msg3");
>
>                   adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4409647944042499/8301167762");
>                    Log.i("4", "msg4");
>
>                   adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);                    
>                    Log.i("5", "msg5");
>
>                  // Convert the default layout parameters so that they play nice with
>                   // ListView.
>
>                   float density = mainActivity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
>                   int height = Math.round(AdSize.BANNER.getHeight() * density);
>                   AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
>                       AbsListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
>                       height);
>                   adView.setLayoutParams(params);
>
>                   AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
>                       .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
>                       .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
>                       .build();
>
>                   adView.loadAd(adRequest);
>               }
>               convertView = adView;
>               return convertView;
>         }
>           return convertView;
>       } else  {
>       if (convertView == null || convertView instanceof AdView) {
>       // If we weren't given a view, inflate one
>          if (convertView == null) {
>              convertView = getSherlockActivity().getLayoutInflater()
>                       .inflate(R.layout.list_item_bxxxx, null);
>       }  
>       // Enter the view of this Bxxxx Attack
>       Bxxxx c = getItem(position);
>
>       TextView titleTextView =
>               (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bxxxx_list_item_titleTextView);
>       titleTextView.setText(c.getTitle());
>       TextView dateTextView =
>               (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bxxxx_list_item_dateTextView);
>       dateTextView.setText(DateFormat.format("EEEE, MMM dd, yyyy  hh : mm a", c.getDate()).toString());
>
>       CheckBox resolvedCheckBox =
>               (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bxxxx_list_item_resolvedCheckBox);
>       resolvedCheckBox.setChecked(c.isResolved());
>
>       return convertView;
>       }
>       return convertView;
>    }          
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
>   @Override
>   public void onResume() {
>       super.onResume();
>       ((BxxxxAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
>       }
>   }
> ```
>
> `03-18 06:52:29.785: D/dalvikvm(932): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
>     03-18 06:52:30.085: I/1(932): msg1
>     03-18 06:52:30.085: I/2(932): msg2
>     03-18 06:52:30.085: D/AndroidRuntime(932): Shutting down VM
>     03-18 06:52:30.095: W/dalvikvm(932): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932): java.lang.NullPointerException
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:228)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.view.View.(View.java:1878)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:281)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.(Unknown Source)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at com.robertrichardson.bxxxyxxxxzxxxLite.BxxxxListFragment$BxxxxAdapter.getView(BxxxxListFragment.java:251)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
>     03-18 06:52:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(932):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are hiding the class variable 'adView' in the new code by declaring a local variable of the same name.  Due to the scope, you're setting convertView to the global adView, which is always null.  Just change "AdView adView =" to "adView ="

Comment: WOW. That was it. Its working great in the emulator. Now all I need to do is add this logic to my List fragment in the program that I want to publish. Thanks for your help:)

Comment: No prob.  BTW welcome to Stack Overflow, and don't forget to select the answer to your question (to close it) if you got what you need.

Comment: Now with my ListFragment , I'm having null pointer exception errors from the activity I'm trying to set within the adView. Do you know the best way to set up a adview, within a fragment?

Comment: It's likely not an adview issue; it may be about the management of your activity lifecycle with fragments.   Don't store a member variable with the activity, retrieve it with getActivity().  There are a number of references that you shouldn't manage yourself in Android because they can change outside of your purview.

Comment: Further edits to the main question make it difficult for others to get useful info out of this. It's also best to open new question for separate topics. I did mean purview: https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Apurview  As to the changes to make, do 'mainActivity = getActivity();' before using it in onCreateView - don't use the stale activity reference.